# C++ to Java(openmp)

Tags: java, c++

I'd appreciate it if you could help on this

Basically what I need to do is to find the best way to load a cpp file through java.

Explaining more, I have a program written in C++ (openmp) and I need to write a Java Gui that will run this file along with some other tasks.

What is the most efficient and easier way to do this? Do you have any online books , or recommendations for it?

Also could this be done through xml? I mean have the xml structure and load the java's gui file and then the .cpp? How could this work?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "load a cpp file"? I assume you're not talking about simply reading the file contents into a string?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the JNI:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Search the web for "JNI getting started" or "JNI tutorial" or "JNI Hello World".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String);`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29). This method invokes another application. Here is some example usage:

```
public void runBtnActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./mycppapp"); // or for Windows "mycppapp.exe"
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // handle here
    }
}
```

Be sure you compiled your C++ application. It is impossible to run the code without compilation. You can try to compile the C++ through Java, using the same method:

```
int success = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"g++", "mycode.cpp"}).waitFor();
```

Comment: If I understood correct, this method is loading an .exe file(compiled). This might be a solution, however what If i want to actually use some methods inside the c++ file from java?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jovial.com/javaAndCpp/java_and_cpp.html
If that doesn't work for you, then you very well may need to compile each of those methods into separate executable files or turn your C++ application into a monitor of sorts, which listens for messages and then takes action base on the received message(s). The former is probably the easiest way to go.